# Problems from user status discord.js v13

Tags: discord.js, member, status

When I had discord.js v12 everything was fine with statuses, but now with discord.js v13 I got the following problem:

```js
message.guild.members.cache.filter(member => member.presence.status === "(status)").size;
```

In this code, it throws an error:

> cannot read property 'status' of undefined

I also checked `message.author.presence.status`, the result is the same.

I also tried something else and it surprised me a little: `message.guild.members.cache.get(bot.user.id).presence.status` and `message.guild.members.cache.get(message.author.id).presence.status` both work.

Comment: Did you enable the intents on the developer portal? https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html#privileged-intents

Comment: I already connected the ones I needed.

Comment: Which ones did you import exactly?

Comment: `GUILDS`, `GUILD_MEMBERS`, `GUILD_BANS`, `GUILD_EMOJIS_AND_STICKERS`, `GUILD_INVITES`, `GUILD_VOICE_STATES`, `GUILD_PRESENCES`, `GUILD_MESSAGES`, `GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS`, `GUILD_MESSAGE_TYPING`, `DIRECT_MESSAGES`, `DIRECT_MESSAGE_REACTIONS`, `DIRECT_MESSAGE_TYPING`.

Answer (score 2):

By using [optional chaining (?.)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining), you are able to 'bypass' the error `cannot read property 'status' of undefined` (Node.js v14 and higher only).

```js
const presence = message.guild.members.cache.filter(member => member.presence?.status === "online");

console.log(presence.size);
```

Note that you will not be able to track the presence from offline users, presence data will return `undefined` instead.

If you receive errors like `Error [DISALLOWED_INTENTS]: Privileged intent provided is not enabled or whitelisted.`, you simply have to follow these steps:

Discord requires bot developers to enable `PRESENCE INTENT` to track presence data from server members. So the first step is to enable this. This can be done in the Developer console:

> https://discord.com/developers/applications/id_of_your_bot/bot

The next thing is to make sure you have enabled the `GUILD_PRESENCES` flag as well, as this is required to track the presence data from server members. So for example:

```js
const { Client, Intents } = require("discord.js");
const bot = new Client({
    intents: [
        // Your other intent flags
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_PRESENCES // This line is required to track presence data
    ]
});
```

Comment: Thanks, you helped me.

Comment: It returns 0 when at least I am online